# Meteor: Dealing with authentication token without registered user

Tags: authentication, meteor

Hard to find a meaningful title. I hope I get clearer now.

I'm building a service which is similar to doodle regarding the authentication model. The user can "create" something (using a form). There will be two different views. One for the creator where he can modify his settings and another one for public access.

I don't want to force users to register / log in. So I came up with a URL structure like doodle has:

- /{some-id} -> public access
- /{some-id}/admin/{some-token} -> settings page for the owner

The question now is how I can deal with this best. Currently I pass the token to all admin related Methods. But I don't feel comfortable with that.

I also thought about some server side session. I found two meteor packages but they are both not actively maintained anymore.

Another idea was to misuse the built in user management but without the user to recognize it. But I don't think that's feasible.

So now I'm asking you if you have a nice way of dealing with this. I hope I made clear what I want to do.

Comment: Have you tried handling access in the router logic? In case you are not using a router yet, have a look at Iron Router.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Iron Router.
Currently I'm subscribing to my data providing the id {some-id} as well as the token {some-token}. That works fine. And if this would be all It would be also fine. But that's only for reading data.
It's more about the methods since I would always provide the token and I would have to pass it some how to each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing it. One way is to reuse Accounts package.

You user id is `{some-id}` and the password is `{some-token}`.

When you create new page. You create new user on server side using [Account.createUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser).

When you enter url `/{some-id}/admin/{some-token}`[Meteor.loginWithPassword](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword).

Comment: Thx - that was something I also had in mind.
I'm just thinking about future changes. I definitely plan to implement the possibility for registering in future. Then I would have a mix up.

Comment: Jakozaur you said there are many ways. Can you show another way?

Comment: Alternatives:

1. Build alternative authentication module, like accounts oauth for token based authentication.

2. Do your own custom when method takes additional argument token (sounds like that's what you do).

3. Same as 2, but use Iron Router to pass that implicitly. (need to do more research)

4. Use some crypto stuff to do signing, to avoid saving info on server.

PS: consider upvoting/marking answer as good to encourage more responses.

Comment: Yes, second is what I am doing. Third option sounds good. Will try to find a solution there.
Regarding upvoting: thx for the tip. But I have not enough reputation right now :(